# can I use the 'switch' statement in any of the questions below? or is the 'else if' the right way to go?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, switch-statement

I am trying to write a function that satisfies the following:

-count from 1 to 100,
-on numbers divisible with 4 print “byfour”,
-on numbers divisible with 6 print “bysix”,
-on numbers divisible with both 4 and 6 print “byfoursix”,
-skip numbers divisible with 7,
-on the number 32 add '!'.
This is what I have, but I was wondering if there is way to use the switch statement, or any more optimal way to write it.

```
function maths(){
  for (let i=1; i<=100; i++){
    if (i === 32){  
    console.log (`${i}!`);
    }
    else if (i % 4 === 0 && i % 6 === 0){
       console.log ("byfoursix");
    }
    else if (i % 4 ===0) {
       console.log ("byfour");
    }
    else if (i % 6 === 0) {
       console.log ("bysix");
    } 
    else if (i % 7 === 0){
       continue;
        }
    else {
      console.log (i);
    }
  }
}

maths();
```

Any input or advice is super appreciated! Thank you

Comment: you can't use `switch` for this case, because switch compares the value directly to the case value for equality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use a switch case if you wanted to by setting the switch parameter to `true` so that it runs, although it's not necessarily a better way to write it.

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      switch (true) {
        case (i === 32):
          console.log(`${i}!`);
          break;
        case (i % 4 === 0 && i % 6 === 0):
          console.log('byfoursix');
          break;
        case (i % 4 === 0):
          console.log('byfour');
          break;
        case (i % 6 === 0):
          console.log('bysix');
          break;
        case (i % 7 === 0):
          break;
        default:
          console.log(i);
      }
}
```